# QT application style does not change between the different windows themes

Tags: windows, qt

Via `qApp->setStyle` you can change the style of your application. What I found is when I run on `Windows 7` with `windows 7 theme` I can switch between:

```
qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"));
qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("WindowsVista"));
qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("WindowsXP));
```

But if I have my `windows 7` setup with `windows classic theme`, I **cannot** switch between those 3. They all look the same.

How can I force my application to look like `Windows Vista` on `Windows Classic theme` PC?

Note: my system returns for `QStyleFacory::keys()`:

- Windows
- WindowsXP
- WindowsVista
- Fusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. On Windows, the "Vista" and "XP" themes are only active if you're using the same or higher theme on the user account. That's not due to Qt, but due to the behavior of the theming APIs on Windows.